# Use Yii2's Autocomplete widget to query more than one table

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, yii2, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Yii2's Autocomplete widget makes it very easy to implement an autocomplete user input field, but the widget's parameters only accept one data model.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-autocomplete.html

I need the autocomplete to query 2 data models (or 2 tables in the database) when trying to auto-populate the user's entry.

Do I have to make my own custom autocomplete functionality? Or is this possible with Yii2's widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Yii2 Autocomplete's `model` parameter, you have to use its `source` parameter, and point it to an endpoint and controller that queries both tables and returns the result each time it's called by Autocomplete.